# Switch between tabs on "Insert Media" dialog

Tags: uploads, javascript, media, media-library

I'm writing a file upload plugin and want to emulate original Wordpress behavior:

1. user uploads file on "Upload Files" tab
2. after upload is complete, "Media Library" tab is activated with just uploaded files selected.

Granted I know how to add a third tab, I want after some to switch to "Media Library" tab, if I could select attachments on the tab, that would be awesome too.

I have browsed docs and js code but failed to find anything.
Snippet would be great, pointing to a proper article will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I found nothing better than:

```
// switch to attachment browser
wp.media.frame.content.mode('browse');
// refresh attachment collection
wp.media.frame.content.view.views._views[".media-frame-content"][0].views._views[""][1].collection.props.set({ignore:(+(new Date()))});
```

Feel free to add proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This could help, I can confirm it works in WordPress 6.5:

```
wp.media.frame.content.get().collection._requery(true);
wp.media.frame.content.get().options.selection.reset();
```